# Best Way to Find Records Created or Modified in the Past "X" Days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, getdate

I'm looking to only select records from a table that have been added or modified within the past "X" number of days, let's say 5 days.

The Accounts table has two columns: CreateWhen and UpdateWhen.

I am using the following:

```
Select * from Accounts where CreateDate >= getdate() -5 or UpdateWhen >= getdate() -5
```

Is this the most efficient way to handle this request?  It seems to work.

Comment: SQL what? MySQL? SQL Server? Other database engine? You should update the tags to contain one of those.

Comment: Sorry I did not specify, but yes, it is MS SQL 2008.

Comment: OK. I've updated the tags in your questions (MS SQL is Sql Server).

Comment: What about the time? Should it be taken into account? If it's 3PM, should a record from 5 days ago but 2PM be shown?

Comment: @Andrew, I'm not really worried about a time as I don't believe this to be particularly time sensitive.  Just looking to go back 2,3 or X days (whatever is decided on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what database engine you're using. Here's solution that should work with SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM Accounts
WHERE DATEADD(d, 5, CreateDate) >= GETDATE()
OR DATEADD(d, 5, UpdateWhen) >= GETDATE()
```

It uses [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function which allows you to add different time intervals to `DateTime` values. In this example you add 5 days (that's what `d` is for as first parameter).

You could do it the other way: add -5 days to `GETDATE()` and compare with `UpdateWhen` and `CreateDate` directly:

```
CreateDate >= DATEADD(d, -5, GETDATE())
```

Pick one that you think is more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am using MS SQL.